# ASP.NET Core multiple singleton service sharing service provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I tried to add two singleton services to ASP.NET Core.

These singletons call `GetRequiredService({TransientService})` from the service provider.

However, since I am not injecting a scoped service, no transient service is created.

But in one singleton case... DI works!

Why does injecting a scoped service into a transient service make only one singleton work?

This is my code:

```
services.AddScoped<ScopedServiceA>();

services.AddSingleton<SingletonA>(serviceprovider => 
 return serviceprovider.GetRequiredService<TransientServiceA>(););

services.AddSingleton<SingletonB>(serviceprovider => 
 return serviceprovider.GetRequiredService<TransientServiceA>(););

services.AddTransient<TransientServiceA>();
```

And `TransientServiceA` constructor looks like this:

```
public TransientService(ScopedServiceA scopedSrv) { ... }
```

The error occurred in this case

> Cannot resolve 'TransientServiceA' from root provider because it requires scoped service

Comment: So you are saying if you remove `services.AddSingleton<SingletonB>(serviceprovider=> 
 return serviceprovider.GetRequiredService<TransientServiceA>(););`, it works?

Comment: @JohanP
I don't know why it works either, but it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure one of them works?

[The documentation goes over this...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped)

> Do not resolve a scoped service from a singleton and be careful not to
> do so indirectly, for example, *through a transient service*. It may
> cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent
> requests. It's fine to:
>
> - Resolve a singleton service from a scoped or transient service.
> - Resolve a scoped service from another scoped or transient service.
>
> **By default, in the development environment, resolving a service from**
> **another service with a longer lifetime throws an exception.**

If you need the scoped service in a singleton then you need to create a scope and get the service from the service provider.

```
public class TransientLifetime : ISingletonA, ISingletonB
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public TransientLifetime(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ScopedLifetime>();
            // do something with the context
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer
it actually works in one singleton service
error occurred after add second singleton
DI was works before adding second singleton